# Como añadir una clase a un elemento creado con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, he creado un elemento html con el siguiente código

```
var x = $("<tr><td class='font-weight-bold'> titulo </td></tr>")
```

ahora me interesa después de hacer algunas validaciones añadirle otras clases mas al elemento td a partir de la variable x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero buscas el td dentro del elemento x  con la función "find" para posteriormente añadirle la nueva clase que desees agregar.

```
$(x).find("td").addClass("myClass");
```

en este ejemplo le aplicara a todos los td que se encuentran dentro del tr,
para especificar a cual td aplicar en caso que sean multiples se requiere
definir a cual.
ejemplo si se requiere aplicar al primer td que encuentre:

```
$(x).find("td:eq(0)").addClass("myClass");
```

ó

```
$(x).find("td:first").addClass("myClass");
```

espero que te sea útil.

Answer (score 1):

si el elemento fue agregado al dom:
puedes hacer un

```
$("parent").find("td").addClass("newclass");
```

si aun se mantiene el la variable:

```
x.replace(/<td(.*?)>/g,"<td class='newclass'>");
```

Comment: El elemento <td>